# How to restrict comma in this regex?

Tags: regex

I am using this regex to match URLs:

```
^((http|https|ftp)://)?(([\w-]+\.)+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Now, I want to disable comma in this regex.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Just [`^((http|https|ftp)://)?(([\w-]+\.)+[^,#?\s]+)([^,]*)?(#[\w-]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/sX4cJ8/1) does not seem enough because of the `[^,]*`. Perhaps, you should not do what you are doing with a regex.

Comment: Can you provide me A url regex , which does not allow comma, and should optionally start with either http or https or ftp

Comment: Please check the one I posted above, and if it is what you are looking for, I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disallow commas in your regex, just exclude it using negated character classes:

```
^((http|https|ftp)://)?(([\w-]+\.)+[^,#?\s]+)([^,]*)?(#[\w-]+)?$
                                    ^^        ^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX4cJ8/1)

Note how I replaced `.*` with `[^,]*` which means *match 0 or more characters other than a comma*. This way you can further adjust the regex including more characters that you do not want to see inside your URLs.